# install rails on Ubuntu fails, probably due to missing bundler gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ubuntu-11.04

I cannot install rails on ubuntu 11.4. 
I tested this twice on my workstation and then on a virtual machine freshly installed.
Rails install will report error.

Hint: Also I cannot find the bundle command which should be installed by 'gem install bundler'

I skipped from the log all successful output.

```
test@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install  ruby-full
[...]
test@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install rubygems1.8
[...]
test@ubuntu:~$ sudo gem install rdoc
[...]
test@ubuntu:~$ sudo gem install bundler
[...]
test@ubuntu:~$ sudo gem install rails
[...]
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.7...
file 'lib' not found
Installing RDoc documentation for activesupport-3.0.7...
[...]
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.0.7...
file 'lib' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your exact issue is, but in my experience ruby packages are nothing but trouble.  Try building ruby from source or better yet, use RVM.  Since I switched I stopped having most of my weird errors.  My 2 cents

Comment: though I am surprised apt-get cannot install ruby and rails properly

Answer (score 2):

As Kelend said, use RubyVersionManager:

http://rvm.io/rvm/install/